# Django intercept adding objects to Many-to-Many field

Tags: python, django

I'm building a Django app and I want to overwrite the default adding to many-to-many field behaviour. Say I want to print out something when a relationship between 2 objects is created.

```
class Foo(Model):
    ...

class Bar(Model):
    foos = ManyToManyField(Foo)
```

Is there anywhere where I can overwrite the add method of the many to many relationship manager class? Something like

```
class ???:
    def add(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
         super().add(obj, *args, **kwargs)
         print(f"{obj} added")
```

and the expected output should be

```
>>> foo1 = Foo.objects.create(...)
>>> bar = Bar.objects.create()
>>> bar.foos.add(foo1)
foo1 added
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding [`ManyRelatedManager`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a34cb5a6d408203f4fbdb364fc9768c026eda224/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L807) `add()` method is not so simple

You can use provided [m2m-changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) signal to get your additional stuff in

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I needed